# How to show that open interval is manifold but closed one is not

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

Prove that we can define manifold's structure for
$1.$ An open interval $A=(0,1) $
$2.B=\{(x,y)\in R^2 | ||(x,y)||<1\}$

And that we can't define manifold's structure for
$3.$ An closed interval $C=[0,1]$
$4.D=\{(x,y)\in R^2 | ||(x,y)||\leq1\}$

for 1. and 2. Can I use the fact that there is a homeomorphism $id$ which map open set A onto open set A in R and open set B onto open set B in $R^2$ and so we have system of coordinate neighborhoods defined in Hausdorff space A and B ? How to prove that we can't define manifold's structure for 3. and 4.?

Comment: For 3 and 4, show that points on the boundary cannot possibly have an open neighborhood homeomorphic to an open set of Euclidean space

Comment: (Topological) manifoldness is a property, not a structure.

Comment: What property should I use here to show that there is no open nbd of 0 homeomorphic to open set of R^n?

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2 are open subsets of Hausdorff, second countable spaces, then, 1 and 2 are Hausdorff and second countable subspaces. Being open, they are already homeomorphic to open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, 1 and 2 are manifolds.
Any open subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the differentiable structure $F_U=\{ (U_a \cap U, \phi_a|_{U_a \cap U}); (U_a,\phi_a) \in F\}$ where $F$ is the standard differentiable structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

But, take in 3 any neighborhood of $1$ or $0$. They are not homeomorphic to an open set of real line (because they are, in subspace topology, of the form [0,a) or (a,1] for a<1  ). A similar argument works for 4.